# want to display one specific row with one radio button select and hiding otherone

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have two radio buttons,what I want is if i select radio button student then class row should be visible else profession row is visible. but at a time only one row is visible.

```
<tr><td>Member</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="member" value="student" onClick = "select_mem()">Student<br></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="member"  value="parent" onClick = "select_mem()">Parent<br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Class</td>
    <td><select name="class" style="width:50px" >
        <option value="1">I</option>
        <option value="2">II</option>
        <option value="3">III</option>
        <option value="4">IV</option>
        <option value="5">V</option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Profession</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="prof"</td></tr>
```

I tried to use this java script

```
function select_mem()
{
    var stu= $('input:radio[name=member]:checked').val();
    document.write(stu);

}
```

Here I was trying to get stu value to see what i will get and then i can put if condition.
Please help me how to do it

Comment: You shouldn't be using document.write() in a function as it is not designed for that. You should create invisible html using `display:none` CSS and use the javascript to show/hide them.

Comment: Not sure if it was intentional, but you didn't close your input. `<td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="prof"</td></tr>`

Comment: [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) clears your document, i.e. it wipes out all the JS and HTML from the page. If you need to check the value of the variable during execution, you can use `console.log(stu)` (or `alert(stu)`).

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
<tr><td>Member</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="member" value="student" onClick = "select_mem(this.value)">Student<br></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="member"  value="parent" onClick = "select_mem(this.value)">Parent<br></td></tr>
<tr id="cls"><td>Class</td>
    <td><select name="class" style="width:50px" >
        <option value="1">I</option>
        <option value="2">II</option>
        <option value="3">III</option>
        <option value="4">IV</option>
        <option value="5">V</option></select></td></tr>
<tr id="pro"><td>Profession</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="prof"</td></tr>

function select_mem(val)
{
    if ( val == "student" ){
        document.getElementById("cls").style.display = "table-row";
        document.getElementById("pro").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("cls").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("pro").style.display = "table-row";
    }
}
```

Comment: :- no its not working actually it is not taking value as student or parent

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the onclick from the HTML bit, and add an ID for each row to show/hide:

```
<tr>
    <td>Member</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="member" value="student">Student<br>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="member" value="parent">Parent<br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="class" style="display:none">
    <td>Class</td>
...
</tr>
<tr id="profession" style="display:none">
    <td>Profession</td>
...
</tr>
```

And change your JS, to bind the click event handler:

```
// Add this piece of script to the page header. Inline, or add to your JS file (preferably).
// On page load, it will attach the handler to the click event. Which means, the code will be executed every time the radio buttons are clicked.
$(function () {
    $("input:radio[name=member]").on("click", function () {
        $("#class").toggle($(this).val() == "student");
        $("#profession").toggle($(this).val() == "parent");
    });
});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/R4gej/

**UPDATE**

As you seem to be having problems using this solution, below you can find the whole code as it should be placed in the page, including the jQuery library link:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("input:radio[name=member]").on("click", function () {
                $("#class").toggle($(this).val() == "student");
                $("#profession").toggle($(this).val() == "parent");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Member</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="member" value="student">Student<br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="member" value="parent">Parent<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="class" style="display:none">
            <td>Class</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="profession" style="display:none">
            <td>Profession</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

**UPDATE #2**

You've posted in the comments that this solution doesn't work. I've tested it a dozen times and can't find a single problem. Are you sure you know what you're doing? Do you know how to debug a piece of Javascript code? Are you adding the jQuery library properly? Are you loading the piece of script in the right place?
It's all more than explained here. Sorry, but I don't see any other way to help you.

Check the following images to see that it works:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Comment: id and style shouldn't be put on row?

Comment: That's what I've done. And used toggle, as the jQuery is already been used.

Comment: its not working, I mean its not displaying class on selecting student and neither on parent

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle link?

Comment: tell me one thing how will it call that function? because inside the script i am having so many functions, so shoudn't I put some mouse event there for calling this function

Comment: I'm updating the answer now.

Comment: Done. Using jQuery you can attach handlers to object events on a JS file, not needing to use onclick, etc, on the HTML code.

Comment: i did add it inline but once i have given command of display: none then it is not displaying any row on selection of any radio button :(

Comment: Would you mind to post your code on jsfiddle so I can have a look?

Comment: got it but how to use that, i can post my code over there how will u view it

Comment: But I really believe this is pointless. You can see the code working on the link I've posted. Your question is pretty trivial, as you can see by the number of answers. I'm assuming you have some basic knowledge on HTML, jQuery (Javascript) and CSS. Did you try to debug your page and see what's going wrong? Did you double check your HTML code for unclosed tags? And so on...

Comment: Here I go... Put every piece of code you have on the designed boxes (HTML, JS, CSS). Save it and post the generated link here.

Comment: want to ask one more thing I am a newbie and learning php, so I am using xampp but there is a problem I am facing. After working for some time when I run my php code on browser it starts displaying that code rather then reading or functioning according to it. It happened  2 days before also I re installed the software but why I am getting this problem again.

Comment: On this one I can't help you. I've worked with PHP, but back on 1999-2003. Now I work with ASP.NET C# MVC.

Comment: did u get it on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tr><td>Member</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="member" value="student" >Student<br></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="member"  value="parent" >Parent<br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Class</td>
    <td><select name="class" style="width:50px" >
        <option value="1">I</option>
        <option value="2">II</option>
        <option value="3">III</option>
        <option value="4">IV</option>
        <option value="5">V</option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td class="Prof">Profession</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="prof"</td></tr>



$(function() { 
       $(".class").hide();
       $(".Prof").hide();
  $('input[type="radio"]').bind('click',function() {
        if($(this).val()=="student")
         { 
             $(".class").show();
         }
        else
          {
             $(".Prof").show();
          }
  });
});
```

Comment: tell me one thing how will it call that function? because inside the script i am having so many functions, so shoudn't I put some mouse event there for calling this function

Comment: This is calling on input type radio change

Comment: i got that but when html code will come to know that it had to go and read some function from script?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `click` use `.on('change')` event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=member]').on('change', function () {
       var value = $(this).val();  //get the selected option
        if(value === 'student'){  //show or hide based on condition
            $('.student').show();
            $('.parent').hide(); 
        }
        else {
            $('.parent').show();
            $('.student').hide();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhWF7/5/)

Working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select_mem() {
        if ($("input[name='member']:checked").val() == "student") {
            $('.studentrow').hide();
            $('.parentrow').show();
        }
        else if ($("input[name='member']:checked").val() == "parent") {
            $('.parentrow').hide();
            $('.studentrow').show();
        }
    }
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Member</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="member" value="student" onClick = "select_mem()">Student<br></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="member" value="parent" onClick = "select_mem()">Parent<br></td>
</tr>
<tr class="studentrow"> 
    <td>Class</td>
    <td>
        <select name="class" style="width:50px" >
            <option value="1">I</option>
            <option value="2">II</option>
            <option value="3">III</option>
            <option value="4">IV</option>
            <option value="5">V</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="parentrow">
    <td>Profession</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="prof"</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

What all I have done is

- Do `if()` on the value of checked radio button
- hide / show rows inside `if()` body

  - to hide\show rows, I specified `class` for each row and called `.show()` and `.hide()` method on them.

Comment: while loading both rows will be visible first?

Comment: What u want? By default which which rows need to be visible?

Comment: after loading first only the radio button row is visible.
Then after selecting radiobutton i want
student: then class row should be visible, with tht i mean both column together
parent: profession row should be visible

Comment: @VivakshaSolanki I didnt get u. Tho u can simply put  `$('.parentrow').hide();`            `$('.studentrow').show();` wherever u want. If u want it to occur on page load u can put it in [`$(document).ready(){}`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). For example, putting  `$('.parentrow').hide()` and `$('.studentrow').hide()` inside `document.ready()` will hide both rows initially. You could just mark the desired reply as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: main problem is that I am not able to retrieve the value of radio button

Comment: Did u tried this: `$("input[name='member']:checked").val()` as I showed above instead of `$('input:radio[name=member]:checked').val()` - the one u used in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep **ID** for two sections..

```
<tr class="hideclass" id="student"><td>Class</td>
<td><select name="class" style="width:50px" >
    <option value="1">I</option>
    <option value="2">II</option>
    <option value="3">III</option>
    <option value="4">IV</option>
    <option value="5">V</option></select></td></tr>
<tr class="hideclass" id="parent">
  <td>Profession</td>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="prof"</td>
</tr>
```

**JQuery**:

```
function select_mem()
{
   var stu= $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
   $('.hideclass').css({"display":"none"});
   $('#'+stu).css({"display":"block"});
}
```

Comment: this can be put inside<script type=text/javascript> tag?

Comment: u havent put the if condition for checking

Comment: We no need to check these things..Because in 2nd line it hide all the rows by finding the class and then in last line it opens current tclicked ...